# magento get color types for product

Tags: magento

I have a product with different colors(white and blue) and different sizes(medium and large)

How do i get those values for a product.

I am trying to get all values for a color using following code:

```
require_once '../magento/app/Mage.php';
        Mage::app();
        $store_id = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
        $config    = Mage::getModel('eav/config');
        $attribute = $config->getAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'color');
        $values    = $attribute->setStoreId($storeId)->getSource()->getAllOptions();
        print_r($values);
```

But i want to get only 2 colors and sizes for a product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are having a product with different colors(white and blue) and different sizes(medium and large)
you must have been confused somewhere as this is not a single product. Rather this is a configurable products with 2 simple product

```
$attrs  = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($product);  
foreach($attrs as $attr) {  
    if(0 == strcmp("size", $attr['attribute_code'])) {  
        $sizess   = $attr['values'];  
    }  
}
```

This would provide attributes options